# How to set up proxying via nginx in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins

My default.conf:

```
upstream jenkins-stream {
    server jenkins:8080;
}

upstream backend-stream {
    server backend:4000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location /jenkins {
        proxy_pass http://jenkins-stream/;
    }
    
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend-stream/;
    }
}
```

My  docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"


services:

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: "ghcr.io/arch/arch-back:latest"
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://arch:NrdhdhdhfQn21@mongodb:27017/?authSource=admin
    networks:
      - my-network
    expose:
      - "4000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:6-jammy
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata6:/data/db
    command: [--auth]
    expose:
      - "27017"
    networks:
      - my-network

  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - my-network
    expose:
      - "8080"

  nginx:
    image: "ghcr.io/arch/arch-nginx:latest"
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
      - backend
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Passwords, logins, repositories are changed

How to configure that when accessed via localhost/api and localhost/jenkins, back and jenkins will open respectively.

The docker-compose logs show this error:

```
nginx      | 2023/06/01 21:57:50 [error] 31#31: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.26.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.26.0.4:4000/api", host: "localhost"
```

I should also point out that there is nginx on the host, but it is switched off

Comment: Your nginx configuration looks OK to me. Are you sure that the `backend` container is listening on port 4000?

Comment: @NickODell I will check, but it doesn't work the same way with Jenkins anyway. It defaults to 8080.